# Github: fixing an accidental milestone or label assignment

Tags: github

Github has a nice interface for searching for groups of issues, and processing them en masse -- such as assigning them to a milestone or adding and removing labels.

Unfortunately this also means one might accidentally reassign a mass of issues to a different milestone or label, thus destroying some carefully-thought-out information.

Is there a way to recover in this situation?

I haven't seen this question asked previously.  One workaround would be to have some protection so a smaller group of people can add/remove certain labels or assign tasks to milestones, but Github's permissions [don't seem to allow such fine-grained control](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization-repository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't have any recourse on the user side (through the GitHub GUI).

Only [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) can check if they have some logs of those operations (possibly managed in a database), and revert the last mass-modification.

Comment: Too bad.  Thanks for your response.